# My computer turns off the monitor but the fans are still on

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

My computer has a biostar hifiA70U3P motherboard with bios version 6.0.4, and with linux when I turn it off, the image disappears, but the fans continue to spin. default/grub and added "acpi=force" but it still didn't work, it seems to be a certain incompatibility with the motherboard, in windows it works normally, can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.